# Git subtree merge, but keep local changes?

Tags: git

There is a branch on a 3rd party repo that I want to add as a subdirectory of my repo. I want to be able to make changes to that 3rd party code, maintain those changes in my repo, and still be able to get updates that were made to the 3rd party repo. In essence, I'm trying to create an overlay.

Following the guide [here](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-7.html) for subtree merging (which describes exactly what I'm trying to accomplish), I've created a remote that points to that 3rd party repo, created a local branch that references the remote branch I want, done a pull on that branch, and used read-tree to copy the local branch's contents in to a subdirectory in master.

I have committed and pushed changes (new files and edits to existing files) in this subdirectory to master. Changes have also been made to various files in the upstream branch. I've been able to pull the changes down to my branch. However, when I attempt to merge as follows,

```
git merge --squash -s subtree --no-commit <my_branch>
```

My local changes are overwritten by the changes upstream. The new files I created are removed and changes I've made to existing files are lost.

Am I doing something wrong or is that the expected behaviour? How can I keep my changes and still merge in changes from upstream?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: @gregseth I'm sorry, but no. Fortunately I ended up not needing to solve it.  I should take another run at it sometime and give the answers here a better shake. Please do let me know if you find a solution that works for you!

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that this is the desired behavior, however I just worked through a similar issue myself.

In my case, turns out the issue was that when the other developer originally added the subtree to the master branch, he added multiple subtrees all at once.  This had the result of changing the SHA of the resulting commit.

In consequence, when I tried to do the subtree merge, git was unable to find a common parent.  This had the end result of git assuming that everything in my local tree was intended to predate the code from the original repo, and upon merge completion the local changes were lost.

I got around this by doing a `git log --oneline` in the subtree's prefix directory, and identifying the first commit into the local repo.

Then,

```
git checkout -b <subtree>_merge <first commit SHA>
git merge --squash -s subtree --no-commit <subtree_remote/ref>
git checkout master
git merge <subtree>_merge
```

This should leave you with the same result you would expect to see from a successful subtree merge from the top.

Comment: For clarity purposes, `<subtree>_merge` is the name of a new branch, so whatever the name. `<first commit SHA>` is the first commit when you initially added the subtree content to your repo, commit SHA that `git log --oneline` will help you remember. Still, what I am worried about is that this procedure doesn't "link" the master repo with the subtree repo `<subtree_remote/branch>`. Eventually, it links it with the newly created "merged" branch, which is an odd combination of your old repo at `<first commit SHA>` with the subtree subdirectory synced with remote, without local changes.

Answer (score -1):

As a general rule, you want to do such operations on a clean working tree. Git would abort if it would need over overwrite non-committed changes.

You can use `git stash` to temporarily store those uncomitted changes, so that you can do the merge, and `git stash pop` to apply them again and remove the stash.

Comment: The local changes have been committed and pushed. I don't have anything to stash. The update is overwriting those changes.. basically, replacing everything with upstream regardless of it's state locally.

I suppose I should use different wording. By "local" there, I mean my origin/master as opposed to  upstream.

Comment: You are doing `-s ours`
. That means it only picks one side of history. What else would you expect?

Comment: Woops, my mistake, I pasted in the wrong info. I'm actually doing `-s subtree`. I'll edit the question accordingly. On a side note, the `-s ours` would have completely ignored the upstream changes, which is the opposite of what I'm experiencing.